# How to share files between iOS app and iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes

I know Google Maps (or VLC used to) lets you share files from iTunes to your iOS Device. Is there a way to share any stuff from iOS app to iTunes and ViceVersa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tutorial that 10 seconds of Googling yielded.

[File sharing from app to iTunes is too easy](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2010/11/file-sharing-from-app-to-itunes-is-too.html)

Comment: well i guess for a newbie ,keywords for searching some thing doesnt quite come up.Thanks for such a quick answer

Answer (score 1):

In the new Xcode, you can do this in the UI:

```
1. Select your project in top left
2. Select target in next column
3. Click on Info tab
4. In Custom iOS Target Properties, hover mouse over any row and click +
5. In popup, select "Application supports iTunes file sharing", then set Value to YES on right
6. Click Validate Settings at bottom to make sure all is good
```